# using torchtext with sequences of text as input

Tags: python, pytorch, text-processing, torchtext

I'm trying to use torchtext for sequence labeling where the sequences are sentences. So each `Example` is a list of sentences and their tags:

```
[ 
  {
    'texts': ["An example.", "It's the data.", "I'm talking about it."],
    'labels': [0,2,0]
  },
  { 'texts': ["This is another example", "This is also data."],
    'labels': [0,1]
  }
]
```

Of course I still want tokenization and vocabulary at the word level, but
there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this. For example, `TabularDataset` expects a list of `Field`s that apply to an element of each example, but I want to map the text field across the list of sentences that constitutes the input.

I thought maybe this is what `NestedField` was for, but it seems to be specifically geared towards character embeddings.

Am I missing something? Is this possible (without too much trouble) with torchtext? I'm perfectly willing to accept no as an answer :)

Comment: Do you have a working answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it using Field and NestedField:

```
NESTING_FIELD = Field(batch_first=True, tokenize=clean_string)
TEXT_FIELD = NestedField(NESTING_FIELD, tokenize=split_sents)
```

Comment: Could you explain a little what's going on exactly?